# JavaScript - Get Raw HTML from XML

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have an XML document that resembles -

```
<Results>
  <Data>
    <div id = 'id_div1'>
     <b>Hello World!</b>
    </div>
  </Data>
</Results>
```

Knowing that my HTML is contained within the 'Data' element, using JavaScript how can I get

```
<div id = 'id_div1'><b>Hello World!</b></div> ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-snip-

#### Edit

it's a lot simpler than all this...

```
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("myxml.xml");
var html = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Data")[0].getElementsByTagName("div")[0]
document.body.appendChild(html);
```

Comment: Maybe I'm having a stupid moment, but what is the difference between your first and second suggestion?  The look identical to me.

Comment: lol... forgot to change it... death by copy and paste.  Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Joseph, The XML I have isn't in a document, but a string. How do I parse that string for the first HTML element?

Comment: @MichaelWarren You can use regex to get it: `var html = myXMLString.match(/.*<Data>(.*)<\/Data>.*/)[1]` PS not the best regex, I know. :P